# I cant send a variable to Blade in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, undefined, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to send a variable to blade view, but throw this error:

**Undefined variable: data (View: D:\wamp\www\tienda\resources\views\cliente.blade.php)**

This is my Route:

```
Route::resource('cliente','ClienteController');
```

This is my Controller Cliente:

```
public function index(){

    $data = Cliente::all();

    return view('cliente',compact($data));
}
```

And my Blade:

```
 @foreach ($data as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->nombre}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Additionally, if a try to do for example this
Controller Cliente:

```
    public function index(){
    return view('cliente', ['name' => 'James']);
}
```

And Blade:

```
{{$name}}
```

That yes work... Only the variables and arrays, doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this on your Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $data = Cliente::all();
    return view('cliente',compact('data'));
}
```

[From the compact documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php): "Each parameter can be either a **string** containing the *name of the variable*, or an **array** of *variable names*. The array can contain other arrays of variable names inside it; compact() handles it recursively. "

Comment: Ohh! the compact Method receive a String, not the variable... I dont see that... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
public function index(){
$data['data'] = Cliente::all();
return view('cliente', $data);
}
```

Then you can catch it in blade as like this

```
 @foreach ($data as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->nombre}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```